# Rails routing gives file not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails application with the following entries in routes.rb:

```
  get '/teachers/welcome', to: 'teachers#welcome'
```

Which means that if I type: http://localhost:3000/teachers/welcome then I should be able to see the welcome view from the teachers controller. But I keep getting File Not Found error. I'm new to Ruby so bear with me.

When I look at the application, the files are there:

app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb

app/views/teachers/welcome.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please watch the naming of you model (without s) but your contoller with s .. and the view name have to match the action name . And run rake routes to check your working routes . + be carefull of the routes order in the routes.rb file .. and will not have any problem in your life with the routes

Comment: How do I run rake routes?

Comment: When I ran rake routes, I noticed that the order caused the error, plus I misspelled a name by using plural.

Comment: You can run rake routes by opening your terminal or cmd if windows .. then change directory (cd myproject) to your project .. then run "rake routes" command

Comment: عرفت كيف ؟ ولاا برجع فسرلك عن جديد ؟؟

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a method(action) 'welcome' in your controller try this

```
get 'teachers/welcome' => 'teachers#welcome'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have everything named properly, like the controller and the view.

app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
  end
end
```

app/views/teachers/welcome.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the first slash

```
get 'teachers/welcome' => 'teachers#welcome'
```

Your Controller:

```
# app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
  end
end
```

Note: you can use a generator to create it automatically:

```
rails generate controller teachers welcome
```